# unsigned char table length

Tags: c, string

I declared a table of unsigned char as follow:

```
unsigned char buf[10]={'1','5',0x00,'8'};
```

in order to know the number of elements of this table i implemented this function

```
int tablength(unsigned char *buf)
{
int i=0;
for (i=0;buf[i];i++)
    ;
return i;
}
```

However this function don't give me the right result when the buffer contains 0 in the middle .Sizeof don't give me the right result since it returns 10 in this case i can't neither use strlen since this is a table of unsigned char.
Do you have any idea to improve this function or any predefined function that help me solve my problem (the result that i 'am  waiting for is 4)

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Um, the table **is** 10 elements in size, regardless of the values, so the result from `sizeof()` is correct.  For *any* static array, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` will give you the array element count, and in this case, `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1, so `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])`=`10/1`=`10`.

Comment: This is not possible, your `[10]` array has implicit `0x0` on the part you didn't initialise. It's not like there's a magic bit _"you didn't initialise me!"_

Comment: Are you expecting `{1,2}` to return `2` and `{1,2,0,0}` to return `4`?

Comment: if you are using C++ then use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).  It will remember the size for you.

Comment: I'am using c @MooseBoys yes i am expecting this result

Comment: @fedi If that's the case then there's no way to do it.  Once the program has been compiled, both cases result in the array being initialized to `{1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`.

Comment: The size IS 10 elements. The method you used currently is how strings are (mostly) built, and therefore of course you can't see beyond the 0. When using C, there is no way to know how many spots in the array were actually initialized (as all contain a value).

Comment: You will have to set the unused portions of the array to a Canary value, some number that cannot exist in your algorithm. When you find the Canary, you stop counting. Doesn't come free and good luck finding a Canary for most algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, since you declared a statically allocated array of 10 elements, the size of the array is 10. Even though you may not have **initialized** every element, there is something filling that space. C++ cannot determine whether the value in the array means anything or not.

Comment: The elements not explicitly initialised are set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
unsigned char x[10] = {1, 2, 3};
```

the variable `x` (an array) has 10 elements, the first three initialized to 1, 2 and 3 and all the others initialized to 0. In other words that definition is absolutely identical to

```
unsigned char x[10] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

An array in C and C++ is just a fixed area of memory and doesn't include a counter of how many "interesting" elements are there.

If you are looking for a container with a variable number of elements consider instead `std::vector` (C++ only). With that `std::vector::size()` returns the current number of elements in the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the array to contain exactly the number of elements you've specified, just declare it without a specific size:

```
unsigned char buf[]={'1','5',0x00,'8'};
cout << sizeof(buf); // should be 4
```

If you want to store a variable amount of data (in C++) use `std::vector` instead of an array.

Otherwise you'll need to keep track of the number of valid elements yourself. There's nothing in the language that will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers cannot know how you would like to use an array instance.
Therefore you must follow the language's semantics. By declaring your array globally or locally, but with the storage class specifier `static` you are initializing every element to 0 on default and your function will work.

`0x00` is false. `0x00` (which same as `0x0`) is a hex number representing `0` (false). This is where your counting loop will stop at - the 3rd element.

---

Another thing you can do is declare your array with non-fixed size.

```
unsigned char buf[]={'1','5',0x00,'8'};
```

In that case, the `sizeof` operator works as expected.
Because that way, you will have an array of 4 elements.

---

`strlen()` obviously won't work as it is designed to work with strings, not a buffer.

---

As for a function that counts on a smarter way:

```
size_t arrcnt (unsigned char source[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = size; i >= 0 && !source[i]; i--);

    return i + 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
printf("size of buf: %u", arrcnt(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Comment: what is the impact of this declaration in term of memory?

Answer (score 0):

buf[i] evaluates to false when buf[i] contains 0.

You cannot do what you want unless you know one value which can never occur in your array between 0 to UCHAR_MAX (255). Say the value is 255, then you first preinitialize the full array to 255 before you start filling it up.

```
 memset(buf, 255, sizeof(char) * sizeof(buf));
```

Then you fill other elements like you want and then you can use the following

```
for(i = 0; buf[i] != 255, ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting :

```
for(int i=0;buf[i]!= 0;i++)
count++;
return count;
```

Comment: for non-zero values only. would this work. otherwise you cant do it.